# Email Activity in a Journey using Salesforce Data Entry to Personalize Content not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I have this code in AMPSCript in an Email that is an activity in Journey Builder with a Data Entry source as Salesforce Data Entry Event (Order created).

The Salesforce Object is Order and I want to reference just the OrderNumber; for that I am usign this AMPScript code to reference the value:

```
set @ordernumber = Order:OrderNumber
```

When going to Preview Test Mode I am receiving this error:

The error message is:

> HTML Version There is an error in your email. Please contact your
>   customer service representative. Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
>   An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See
>   inner exception for detail.
>
> Script Expression: Order:OrderNumber
>
> An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script
>   Expression: Order:OrderNumber
>
> Invalid Content:  set @ordernumber = Order:OrderNumber

Could you please advise me about what am I doing wrong ? Initially, my understanding is that the way to reference Data Entry values from Salesforce Data is in this way.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Enrique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Salesforce data (or any data that has field names including characters such as ":") you need wrap your attribute call in brackets. So your variable declaration should be:

```
set @ordernumber = [Order:OrderNumber]
```

Comment: It works fine now ! Thanks a lot for your help Jason !

Comment: Glad to help! Can you please mark this as answered? Good luck with your journey set up!!